# How does this binary.read know when to stop?

Tags: go

Please note this is pseudo code and I am summarising.I am reading some source code from inside a function:

```
maxKeyLen  := 100 * 1024 * 1024
maxValueLen  := 100 * 1024 * 1024
var klen, vlen uint32
binary.Read(p.buffer, binary.BigEndian, &klen)

 if klen > maxKeyLen {
    return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("key exceeds max len %d, got %d bytes", maxKeyLen, klen)
}
```

At what point does the binary.Read stop? Because straight after this there is another read:

```
key := make([]byte, klen)
_, err := p.buffer.Read(key)
if err != nil {
    return nil, nil, err
}

binary.Read(p.buffer, binary.BigEndian, &vlen)
if vlen > maxValueLen {
    return nil, nil, fmt.Errorf("value exceeds max len %d, got %d bytes", maxValueLen, vlen)
}
```

Where p.buffer is defined via:

```
buff := new(bytes.Buffer)
io.Copy(buff, r)
p.buffer = buff
```

And r is some data that has been passed in.

At first I thought the answer was at 4 bytes it stops. But that's not true because the maxkeylen checks for greater than that. So how does the binary.read know when to stop as there is more data ahead, because the next binary read on for the vlen then finds stuff?

Comment: binary.Read reads exactly the size of data required to fill the `data` argument. So yes, it reads exactly 4 bytes for a `uint32` and stops.

Comment: `klen` will be assigned the value of 4 bytes (uint32) read from `p.buffer`, interpreted as big-endian. It will not be assigned the number of bytes read.

Comment: @jimB Are you sure, because that would mean the klen > maxKeyLen condition would never be true, because klen is at most 4 bytes?

Comment: Yes. `klen` is the value read from the buffer, not the number of bytes that was read.

Comment: @jimB I see. So just to confirm, that if statement will never get triggered then? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The if statement will be triggered if the value read into `klen` is greater than 104857600. The same with `vlen`. Both of those calls will always read exactly 4 bytes, because that's the size of a `uint32`, but the value could be anything in `[0, 4294967295]`

Comment: @jimb Ok that makes sense. But in that case what is the point of the if statement? I thought it was to prevent key lengths which are too many bytes big (bigger than 100bytes?). But if klen is always 4 bytes, why would the function care what the value is numerically between 0 and 4294967295. Thanks again.

Comment: You're not showing us the rest of the code. These look like they are there to indicate the size of the following data in a length-prefix encoding scheme. The values then should be used to read the correct number of bytes for the corresponding data.

Comment: @jimb This is the source code I am reading: https://github.com/packetzoom/logzoom/blob/master/input/filebeat/parser.go I don't blame you if you don't want to read that!

Comment: it's is exactly how I described, klen and vlen are used to allocated the correct size slices in order to read in the full key and value.

Comment: @jimb The penny has finally dropped! Now I get it.

Answer (score 3):

When questioning the superheros of Go, always refer to their actual source code in question:

https://golang.org/src/encoding/binary/binary.go?s=4201:4264#L132

```
142 func Read(r io.Reader, order ByteOrder, data interface{}) error {
143     // Fast path for basic types and slices.
144     if n := intDataSize(data); n != 0 {
```

Line 144 shows an example of reading the initial size of know types, and iterating or copying as needed later in that scope.

In your code example above, it will be the 4 byte length of klen which is an `uint32`.  That is, it will read 4 bytes from `p.buffer` into klen.

It gives a hint in the documentation:

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/binary/#Read

```
func Read(r io.Reader, order ByteOrder, data interface{}) error
```

> Read reads structured binary data from r into data. Data must be a pointer to a fixed-size value or a slice of fixed-size values. Bytes read from r are decoded using the specified byte order and written to successive fields of the data.

Comment: the Read function isn't checking the "fixed size" of p.buffer, it's checking the size of the type for `data`. The `r` argument is just an `io.Reader` and doesn't require a size.

Comment: ah. ur right. that's what I get for answering on a mobile and reading too fast. updated.